# NodeMCU Devkit not recognized by pc , unable to upload code

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I was given the nodemcu devkit v0.9 with code on it already uploaded using Arduino IDE, I have been trying to upload to this again but the Board would appear in device manager but then I would try to upload using arduino IDE and receive , com error.

I have tried different usb cables, different ports , and now there is simply a blue light on steady when the board is plugged into usb. The user button no longer turns on the small blue light , and my comp does not recognize the board being plugged in our out at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated as this has been very frustrating.

Comment: If you use a terminal program can you get the NodeMCU prompt up at all?

Comment: I'm in the same situation but with devkit v1, check out my question. Maybe you can do something similar to make it work.

Comment: Ended up swapping board out for another ,  think I may have bricked original one

Answer (score 1):

You should try the ESPlorer, really good with the NodeMCU. If you still have problems you should use the esplorer to flash the NodeMCU, try a custom firmware from the nodemcu builds.

please if u still have problems please let us know so we can help you further